# Which scope use to get the access token for Microsoft credential

Tags: azure, api, bearer-token, microsoft365-defender

I'm trying to do postman access token request to reach the following [api](https://api-eu.securitycenter.windows.com/api/vulnerabilities?$filter=publishedOn%20ge%202022-01-01T00:00:00Z) :

however the result returned is always the same:

> ```
> "error": {         
> "code": "Unauthorized",     
> "message": "Unauthorized",   
> "target": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"       
> }
> ```

POST : https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token

Body:

> client_id : my client id
> scope :https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
> client_secret : my client secret
> grant_type : client_credentials

Header:

> Content-Type : x-www-form-urlencoded

The response return me a token that is apparently not recognized by the first request...

I've tried several scopes such as : /.default, user.read openid profile offline_access, https://graph.microsoft.com/.default...
Even if they are all returning me a token, none of them seems to work.
I've also added the right to WindowsDefenderATP > Vulnerability.read, from the azure portal.

Is the problem the scope? What scope should I use if I have a client credential grant type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [page in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/exposed-apis-create-app-webapp?view=o365-worldwide).

You need an *application permission* since you are making the request with only application credentials.
In this case I think you need the *Vulnerability.Read.All* permission.
Don't forget to grant admin consent after adding the required permission.

Here is the scope you should use:

```
https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/.default
```